# Absorption Refrigerator evaporator code error

Tags: matlab

I'm an undergraduate student working on a simulation for an absorption refrigerator. I found this PhD level thesis that had MATLAB code for the evaporator for an absorption refrigeration system, which is as follows:

```
%%Evaporator 
function [ output ] = evaporator( f1,f13,T13,h11,Cpw,UAe)
    F =@(x) [x(1)-(f1*(((-0.00125397*(x(2)-273.2)^2)+(1.88060937*(x(2)-273.2))+2500.559)-h11));
    x(1)-(f13*Cpw*(T13-x(3))); 
    x(1)-(UAe*((T13-x(2))-(x(3)-x(2)))/log((T13-x(2))/(x(3)-x(2))))];
    x0 = [211/2.89;3+273.2;282];

    % Make a starting guess at the solution 
    Options = optimset('Display','iter'); 
    G = fsolve(F,x0, Options); % Call optimizer 
    Qe=G(1,1); 
    Te=G(2,1); 
    T14=G(3,1); 
    output(1)=Qe; 
    output(2)=Te; 
    output(3)=T14;
end
```

I tried running the code through simulink but it gave an error saying it did not recognize the symbol "@(x)". Is it something to do with the optimizer? Also if there are any other syntax error, could you please point them out? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I have edited your question to be formatted code (indent by 4 spaces).  Please do so in the future.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?  How exactly are you running the code?  What are you typing into MATLAB's Command Prompt?  `@(x)` has been around forever.  It simply defines `F` to be an anonymous function.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use anonymous functions in simulink.

Comment: @AnderBiguri But converting `F` into a proper function should work, right?

Comment: @beaker I think it should. My simulink is a bit rusty.

Comment: Its Matlab 8.0 (2012b) and I am actually trying to put this code in the user-defined function block of simulink but ended up with errors while running the code. Do i need to type the code in the workspace as well, or is it incorrect to use @(x). how to rectify it?